# Contingent Header Category Label

Tags: php, wordpress

Right now the header has a bit of code in it that queries the section name and then uses that section name as the h1 title in the page.  It works fine.  However, I want to selectively break that operation in certain categories and give myself the ability to manually enter the h1 title for a given section.  Here's what I'm struggling with: how can I maintain the automatic query and title selection in most instances, but selectively break it in a given category (the 'blog' category, for starters)?

Thanks for taking a look, I appreciate your help!

**Here's the code that drives the existing function (it's the get_the_section_name part):**

```
    <?php if(!is_home()){?>
    <div class="section <?php echo get_the_section_name();?>">
        <?php 
        $sectitle = get_the_section_name();
        $sectitle = str_ireplace("-"," ",$sectitle);
        echo '<h1>' . $sectitle . '</h1>';?>

        <p class="breadcrumbs">
            <?php
            if(function_exists('bcn_display'))
            {
                bcn_display();
            }
            ?>
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="columns">       
    <?php } ?>
```

Here's a page that shows what it looks like displayed (see the title in the blue graphic underneath the main nav near the top of the page): http://69.20.59.228/category/blog/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Insert following code before line

```
echo '<h1>' . $sectitle . '</h1>';?>
```

Simply add more elements to `$special_categories` array

```
$special_categories = array(
    "blog" => "Special blog title",
    "other category" => "Another special category title",
);

if (array_key_exists($sectitle, $special_categories)) {
    $sectitle = $special_categories[$sectitle];
}
```

Comment: it's not working... is there a missing parenthesis on the end of the "if (array_key_exists" statement?

Comment: ok, I just added another parenthesis and it's working now...  thanks!